# How to can i change page column layout for search result page when result not available?

Tags: magento2, layout, catalogsearch, page-layouts, search-result

I want to make 1 column layout for search result page when result not available.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a block rewriting the search results page say

> Result.php

and in that

```
public function getNoResultText()
    {
        if ($this->catalogSearchData->isMinQueryLength()) {
            return __('Minimum Search query length is %1', $this->_getQuery()->getMinQueryLength());
        }

        return $this->getLayout()->getBlock('zero_res');
    }
```

Now create:-

> Custom/Handles/view/frontend/layout/zero_res.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Custom\Handles\Block\Result" name="zero_res" template="zero_res.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```